# Square payment PHP SDK returns null

Tags: php, android, square-connect

I'm making a payment using [Square Payment PHP SDK](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk)
1. Generate a `nonce` from a mobile app then send to my server to create a payment request.
2. My server receives the `nonce` correctly  though after i run `$payments_api->createPayment($body);` i get a `null` exception.
Here is my code:

```
        $access_token = 'MY_ACCESSS_TOKEN';
        $location_id = 'LOCATION_ID';
        $params = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $nonce = $params['nonce'];//received from post request
        # setup authorization
        $api_config = new \SquareConnect\Configuration();
        $api_config->setHost("https://connect.squareupsandbox.com");
        $api_config->setAccessToken($access_token);
        $api_client = new \SquareConnect\ApiClient($api_config);
        # create an instance of the Location API
        $locations_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationsApi($api_client);

        $payments_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\PaymentsApi($api_client);
        //$payments_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi($api_client);

        $body = new \SquareConnect\Model\CreatePaymentRequest();
        $amountMoney = new \SquareConnect\Model\Money();
        $amountMoney->setAmount(100);
        $amountMoney->setCurrency("USD");

        $body->setSourceId($nonce);
        $body->setAmountMoney($amountMoney);
        $body->setLocationId($location_id);

        $body->setIdempotencyKey(uniqid());

        try {
            $result = $payments_api->createPayment($body);

            $payment_data = $result->getPayment();
           return $result;
        } catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
           //returns null
            return $e->getResponseBody();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting I found the error `error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile:` when making curl requests.
I resolved it by:
1. Downloading the `cacert.pem`
2. Copy pasting `cacert.pem` and renaming it to `curl-ca-bundle.crt`
3. Modifying the php.ini file `curl` to `curl.cainfo="xammp path\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt`
*Note i was working on local xammp with a self signed ssl.*